# Non-asymptotic convergence rates for gradient descent

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I'd like to know how the number of steps needed for gradient descent depend on properties of the Hessian in **non-asymptotic** regime.

More specifically, number of gradient descent steps needed to obtain given accuracy target $\epsilon$ where $1/\text{dimensions}<\epsilon$. This setting corresponds to high dimensional optimization in finite precision arithmetic.

Empirically I'm finding that entropy of Hessian spectrum is a much better predictors of the number of steps than Hessian condition number, which is what most existing optimization literature uses.

A simple experiment: generate various random diagonal Hessians in $n$ dimensions, start at $(1,1,\ldots)$ and count the number of steps until gradient descent reduces the objective by a factor of $n$. Plot it against Hessian condition or Hessian spectrum entropy. The latter gives a better predictor. Any literature pointers appreciated!

[image]
[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-gradient-convergence-entropy.nb)

Comment: Interesting question. But I have a comment. The fact that many optimization literatures focus on the condition number is due to that they usually use stepsize 1/L or 2/(L+\mu), where L is the largest eigenvalue of the Hessian (roughly speaking). If the effective dimension is much smaller than n and only finite precession is needed, then have you considered change the stepsize to 1/M where M is the largest eigenvalue in the effective dimension?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04299

Answer (score 1):

For quadratic optimization, it's a classical result that dates at least to [(Hestenes and Stiefel, 1952)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/049/jresv49n6p409_A1b.pdf) that the error can be written as a polynomial function of the Hessian. More precisely, for a quadratic function $f(x) = (1/2) x^\top H x + b^\top x$, there exists a degree-$t$ polynomial $P_t$ (which we can often compute) that verifies
$$
x_t - x^\star = P_t(H)(x_0 - x^\star)
$$

Taking norms on both sides, applying Gram-Schmidt we then have
$$
\|x_t - x^\star\| = \text{tr}(P_t(H)) \|x_t - x^\star\| = \sum_i P_t(\lambda_i) \|x_t - x^\star\|
$$
and you can bound the error by a polynomial function of all the eigenvalues (not just the extremes).
$$

Comment: The annoying thing is that degree of the polynomial depends on number of steps, so this makes it hard to see the connection between eigenvalues and number of steps needed

Comment: True, but I don't think there's a way around this. Asymptotically in the number of iterations we can show (at least for gradient descent) that the rate converges to a regime where only the extremal eigenvalues matter. So if you want an expression that doesn't depend on t, it will depend on the condition number :-(